# Use tapir router with play-framework without jsr330

Tags: scala, playframework, tapir

I use play framework with tapir. My usage similar to sample https://github.com/gaeljw/tapir-play-sample

And we define router like this:

```
@Singleton
class ApiRouter @Inject() (apiController: BookController, apiDocumentation: ApiDocumentation, bookEndpoints: BookEndpoints)(implicit
    val materializer: Materializer,
    ec: ExecutionContext
) extends SimpleRouter {
  
  ...

  override def routes: Routes = {

    openApiRoute
      .orElse(booksListingRoute)
      .orElse(booksStreamingRoute)
      .orElse(oneOfStreamingRoute)
      .orElse(addBookRoute)
      .orElse(getBookRoute)
  }
```

**routes**

```
->         /        routers.ApiRouter
```

Promblem, that our implementation of `@Singleton` is [scaldi jsr330](https://github.com/scaldi/scaldi-jsr330), that has some [problems](https://github.com/scaldi/scaldi-jsr330/issues/1)

How can I remove dependency on jsr330 (`@Singleton`) and use router as singleton without it? Note that just not using singleton leaves to performance problem.

Comment: I'm curious about the performance issues you had by not declaring the Router as Singleton: do you have numbers? I would have expected the DI framework to still create only one instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the *routes* file at all as all your routes are defined as code, you can get rid of the *routes* file and declare the `ApiRouter` class directly in *application.conf* in the `play.http.router` key.

---

That being said, there's no reason to necessary use DI. You could also define everything in an `object`.